# Networking setup in docker

Tags: security, ssl, networking, docker, mqtt

If I have a network setup in Docker, as follows
[image: docker networking]

Here `MQTT` and `Nodejs` are two separate docker containers.

Do I also have to use TLS for securing `channel A`? Do I even have to secure `channel A`? I guess no, as it is just a container to container channel. Am I correct?

I am a newbie as far as Docker is concerned but I've read that `docker0` will allow containers to intercommunicate but prevent outside world from connecting to containers, until a port is mapped from the host to a container.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear fro the question if the nodejs and mqtt broker are in the same docker container or in 2 separate containers, but...

The interlink between 2 docker containers for a port not mapped to the host will be on the internal virtual network, the only way to sniff that traffic will be from the host machine so as long as the host machine is secure that traffic should be secure with out the need to run a SSL/TLS listener.

If both the nodejs app and the broker are within the same docker container then they can communicate over `localhost` so not even over the virtual network interconnect so again not need to add SSL/TLS.

Comment: Here MQTT and Nodejs are two separate docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about the traffic unless the host system has potential hostile containers or users... but sometimes my imagination fails me.

You can use the deprecated --link flag to keep the port from being mapped to the host (IIUC):

```
docker run --name mqtt mqtt:latest & docker run --name nodejs --link mqtt nodehs:latest
```

Again, IIUC, this creates a private network between the two containers... 
Evidence of that is a `netstat -an |grep EST` does not show connections between containers that are --link'd this way, even if one the target port is open to the world